# Optimization of the structure and database MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following relationships:

```
order_products (1 or n) ———————— (1) orders (1) ————————— (1) transactions
    ...                                (1)                         (1)
    price                               |                           |   
    qty                                 |                           |
                                       (1)                         (1)
                                      users                       users
```

1. Should I leave 2 relationships to users table as above?
2. I intend to show the total order amount or get the transaction amount will query the order_products table. This is better than adding the amount field at 1 of two tables (or both) orders, transactions?.

Comment: What does transactions tell us that order's doesn't

Comment: @Strawberry I don't understand your answer.

Comment: Does `transactions` mean `payments` ? An order may have multiple payments and the user related to the payment is the account in the system which entered the payment. While the user for an order is more like a `client` as it does not matter who actually created the order (the client himself or someone from your sales department) - as long as the order is still related to the correct `client`. And a `client` may have multiple orders ...

Comment: @IVOGELOV ```transactions ``` contain all website transactions, my client makes payment at ```paypal_transactions```, ```alipay_transactions ``` reference to ```transactions```.

Comment: I separate sub-transaction tables because the data received from the payment gateways between them is different.

Comment: Still, it does seem that if there really is a 1-1 correlation between transactions and orders (and users means the same thing in both contexts), then the users reference to one or other of those tables is redundant and should be removed.

Comment: My point is that even if most of the time you have 1 payment per order - sometimes there might be a refund so there could be more than 1 transaction per order. And since you know the order of any given transaction - you can find the user from the order.

Answer (score 0):

Start by deciding which relationship exists in each case:

- 1-1 -- the two tables should probably be merged together.
- 1:many -- the "many" table has a column with the ids into the "one" table.
- many:many -- This needs an extra table with 2 ids (one for each table).